# What is the conjugacy class equation for $\mathbb{Z_{10}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to gain intuition of the conjugacy class equation and I do have a working knowledge of what a conjugate class is, cosets and Langrange's Theorem after hearing a couple of my friends talk about their problems in a study room and reading articles on wikipedia.

My belief is that the centralizer subgroups are for $\mathbb{Z_{10}}$ are formed by all the elements themselves. I've found out that 2,4,5,6 and 8 don't have inverses in this group. What I've also noticed is that for any $ x \in \mathbb{Z_{10}}$ and for a specific $ g \in \mathbb{Z_{10}}$ that has an inverse, $gxg^{-1} = x$ If I do the index per element $x \in \mathbb{Z_{10}}$ I would get $[\mathbb{Z_{10}}: C(x)] = 1$ each time where $C(x)$ is the centralizer of $x$. When I add them together I have: 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 10. Is this right?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb Z_{10}$? It usually means the additive group of integers modulo $10$, but you say you've found out that $2,4,5,6,8$ have no inverses...which is not even possible in a group.

Answer (score 2):

In any abelian group, every element is its own conjugacy class, so the class equation will take the form $1+ \ldots +1 = |G|$.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely right.  You can either use the approach with centralizers as you have done, or notice that it is an Abelian group, so that $gxg^{-1}=xgg^{-1}=x$, as you have also figured out.  In any case, each conjugacy class is a singleton, so that we have $1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=10$.

Using the fact that a group is Abelian, what can you say about the class equation of any (finite) Abelian group?